# setup cgi-bin server python with apache2.4.18

Tags: python, apache

I have my `index.py` in `/var/www/cgi-bin`

My `index.py` looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

My apache2 `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin>

  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

</Directory>    

</VirtualHost>
```

Let me know if anything else also require any modification, I have already  enabled cgi.

The problem is no matter whatever URL I visit I keep on getting error **Not Found** [localhost](http://localhost) , or [localhost/index.py](http://localhost/index.py)

Comment: My Apache knowledge is a little rusty, but does `index.py`  have its execute permission bits set?

Comment: yes `chmod 755`

Comment: Did you try 127.0.0.1 directly, instead of localhost?

Comment: Did that, no use.

Comment: Change your listening port in /etc/apache2/ports.conf from 80 to some other port like 8080 and then run 'sudo systemctl daemon-reload' and 'sudo service apache2 restart' and then try 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: @Manel no that's not the issue, apache setup was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Enable `CGI` `a2enmod cgid`

`chmod a+x /var/www/cgi-bin/index.py` but check `cgi-bin` directory owner is `wwwdata` ?

Need a `directory` definition on every `Virtualhost` !

Some time required `restart` for killing all `apache` threads !

```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs #A include B if owner are same !
   <Directory /var/www/htdocs/cgi-bin/ >
            FallbackResource /index.py
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes

            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AddHandler cgi-script .py

    </Directory>
```

Comment: `Options` is what was missing.

My settings are a bit different `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI`

Comment: `CGI` mean **Common Gateway Interface** , `-Indexes` for never declared contained files. `-FollowSymLinks` Sorry i can't set  a filter every cgi-script on this sever(but got local access to more cgi-scripts ). Did you know my .py script names ? Happy injections(of course you need time hash primary key and variables pattern) !

Answer (score -1):

use this file to run cgi script:

```
import cgi;
import cgitb;cgitb.enable()
```

Comment: No this is not the problem, the problem is with apache setup.